# How to tell for a particular request that all available worker threads are BUSY

Tags: udp, netty

I have a high-rate UDP server using Netty (3.6.6-Final) but notice that the back-end servers can take 1 to 10 seconds to respond - i have no control over those, so cannot improve latency there.

What happens is that all handler worker threads are busy waiting for response and that any new request must wait to get processed, over time this response comes very late. Is it possible to discover for a given request that the thread pool is exhausted, so as to intercept the request early and issue a server busy response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `ExecutionHandler` configured with an appropriate `ThreadPoolExecutor`, with a max thread count and a bounded task queue. By choosing differenr `RejectedExecutionHandler` policies, you can either catch the `RejectedExecutionException` to answer with a "server busy", or use a "caller runs policy", in which case the IO worker thread will execute the task and create a push back (but that is what you wanted to avoid).

Either way, an execution handler with a limited capacity is the way forward.